# how to get the documentation of a julia function in a vscode notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia

I want to get the documentation of a Julia function in a notebook (.ipynb file) on vscode:

```
?cc
```

gives:

```
ParseError:
# Error @ e:\Julia Forks\TimeSeries-Cepstral-Clustering\example\example.ipynb:1:1
? cc
╙ ── not a unary operator

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ e:\Julia Forks\TimeSeries-Cepstral-Clustering\example\example.ipynb:1
```

Or:

```
Docs.doc(cc)
```

gives:

```
ParseError: KaTeX parse error: No such environment: verbatim at position 7: \begin{̲v̲e̲r̲b̲a̲t̲i̲m̲}̲ cc(series::Abs…

Calculate the cepstral coefficients of the AR(p) process for each asset in the series.

\section{Arguments}\begin{itemize} \item \texttt{series::AbstractMatrix}: a matrix of time series observations, with each row representing an asset and each column representing a time step.

\item \texttt{p::Int}: the order of the AR(p) process.

\item \texttt{n::Int}: the number of cepstral coefficients to calculate.

\end{itemize} \section{Returns}\begin{itemize} \item \texttt{cc_vec::AbstractMatrix}: a matrix of cepstral coefficients, with each row representing an asset and each column representing a cepstral coefficient.

\end{itemize}
```

It is not clean! Any better way?

Comment: In the REPL/Terminal `?` and `Docs.doc` work. In VSCode, if you install the Julia plugin, you additionally get the documentation when you hover over the command. In regular Jupyter notebooks `?` works as well. The VSCode Jupyter plugin is a bit incomplete/buggy, not everything works in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround can be following.

Define the macro:

```
macro h(x)
    quote
        display("text/markdown", @doc $x)
    end    
end
```

Now you can do `@h myfun`, for an example:

[image]